# How to zip a file using gzip and execl in c

Tags: c

I tried to zip a file using gzip and execl in c. but in my code it didn't work. If my current folder is "new" how to find a file called a.txt and zip that file using gzip and execl in c. I tried it using below code.

```
execl("/bin/sh","bash","gzip","-c","a.txt > foo.zip",NULL);
```

Comment: The `gzip` command doesn't to ZIP *archives*. `gzip` only does *compression*.

Comment: so how do i zip a file using execl in c

Answer (score 0):

Don't use gzip, run [the actual `zip` binary](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) instead.

Also, there's no need to run a shell, `zip` is perfectly capable of writing its own output.